Is there a name or term for a topological space that is a manifold "almost everywhere"?
Consider the classic example of a topological space shaped like the plus sign: "$+$".
If we look at a neighborhood about the central junction of this cross, then we know that we don't have a homeomorphism to $\mathbb R$, and as a result our space can't be a manifold. But if we were to take a "one-dimensional measure" of the space, it would appear that "almost every" point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and the poorly behaved points have measure zero.
There are a whole class of spaces that would be manifolds locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ were it not for troublesome regions with n-dimensional measure zero. These spaces would seem like important objects ripe for application and study, but I don't recall seeing any term formalized for them. Is there a common name and usage for these "almost everywhere" manifolds?
Perhaps I just haven't run across any books or papers that deal with these spaces.

To me this sounds like a ramified (branched) cover.

See this and this

@183orbco3 Thanks, I saw stratified spaces, orbitfolds, and stratifolds off of the links you gave. They seem to have slightly different criteria from what I was thinking about, especially since it lookes like stratifolds are adressing smoothness and not homeomorphisms. Maybe "parafold" is a nice compact word to use if it's not taken, since "para-" means "close to", or "beside".
